# calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler: not called, ETA not get

Tags: mapkit

Working on Map application, I want to find the Expected time to reach destination point without use any api like maps.google.
any help?

Below is the code :

```
MKPlacemark* placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:new_coordinate addressDictionary:nil];

MKMapItem* destinationMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
MKDirectionsRequest *request = [MKDirectionsRequest new];
request.source = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];
request.destination = destinationMapItem;
request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile;
MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    MKRoute *route = response.routes.firstObject; 
    NSMutableString *Str = [NSMutableString new];
    int counter = 1;
    for (MKRouteStep *step in route.steps) {
        [Str appendFormat:@"%d %@", counter, step.instructions];
        counter++;
    }
}];
```

No Error given but not called portion inside `calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler`..